for loop unrolling not working as expected
I have a module with some parameters. Those are used in a for loop that I would have thought would unroll the contents. In the end, there would be no for loop or index, just a big list of repetitive logic.
I'm obviously not understanding this as when I try to use iverilog to start testing the module, it complains with many errors:
command being run: iverilog -g2012 -o graph/crossbar.vvp -s crossbar_tb src/defines.sv test/crossbar_tb.sv src/crossbar.sv
src/crossbar.sv:54: error: A reference to a wire or reg (`m') is not allowed in a constant expression.
src/crossbar.sv:54: error: Part select expressions must be constant.
src/crossbar.sv:54:      : This lsb expression violates the rule: ((m)*('sd32))+(('sd32)-(MASK_SIZE))

m in this case is an integer index in a for loop that in my mind would go away during the unroll.
The module code, its logic may be wonky as I haven't tested it at all yet. But, I don't understand why it won't unroll as expected while trying to write a test.
`default_nettype none

module crossbar
#(
  parameter MASTERS = 1,
  parameter CHANNELS = 1,
  parameter MASK_SIZE = 4
)
(
  input  logic                       i_clock,
  input  logic                       i_reset_n,

  // Inputs from masters
  input  logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]   i_wbm_we,     // Write enable
  input  logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]   i_wbm_cyc,    // Cycle status
  input  logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]   i_wbm_stb,    // Strobe
  input  logic [MASTERS * 32 - 1:0]  i_wbm_addr,   // Address read from master
  input  logic [MASTERS * 32 - 1:0]  i_wbm_data,   // Data read from the master

  // Outputs to masters
  output logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]   o_wbm_err,    // Error
  output logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]   o_wbm_ack,    // Acknowledge
  output logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]   o_wbm_stall,  // Stall
  output logic [MASTERS * 32 - 1:0]  o_wbm_data,   // Data write from the master

  // Outputs to channels
  output logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]   o_wbc_we,     // Write enable
  output logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]   o_wbc_cyc,    // Cycle status
  output logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]   o_wbc_stb,    // Strobe
  output logic [CHANNELS * 32 - 1:0]  o_wbc_addr,   // Address read from master
  output logic [CHANNELS * 32 - 1:0]  o_wbc_data,   // Data read from the master

  // Inputs from channels
  input  logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]          i_wbc_err,    // Error
  input  logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]          i_wbc_ack,    // Acknowledge
  input  logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]          i_wbc_stall,  // Stall
  input  logic [CHANNELS * 32 - 1:0]         i_wbc_data,   // Data write from the master
  input  logic [CHANNELS * MASK_SIZE - 1:0]  i_wbc_mask    // Mask for address space
);

logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0] channel_in_use [$clog2(MASTERS):0];

integer m; // Master loop index
integer c; // Channel loop index

always_ff @(posedge i_clock) begin
  // Loop over each master
  for (m = 0; m < MASTERS; m = m + 1) begin
    // New request from master m
    if (i_wbm_cyc[m] == 'b1 && i_wbm_stb[m] == 'b1) begin
      // Loop over each channel
      for (c = 0; c < CHANNELS; c = c + 1) begin
        // Found the requested channel, not in use
        if (i_wbc_mask[c * MASK_SIZE + MASK_SIZE - 1:i_wbc_mask * MASK_SIZE] == i_wbm_addr[m * 32 + 32 - 1:m * 32 + (32 - MASK_SIZE)] && channel_in_use[c] == 0) begin
          channel_in_use[c] <= m;
          o_wbm_stall[m] <= 'b0;
          o_wbm_err[m] <= 'b0;
        end

        // Found the requested channel, in use
        else if (i_wbc_mask[c * MASK_SIZE + MASK_SIZE - 1:i_wbc_mask * MASK_SIZE] == i_wbm_addr[m * 32 + 32 - 1:m * 32 + (32 - MASK_SIZE)] && channel_in_use[c] != 0) begin
          o_wbm_stall[m] <= 'b1;
          o_wbm_err[m] <= 'b0;
        end

        // requested channel not found
        else begin
          o_wbm_stall[m] <= 'b0;
          o_wbm_err[m] <= 'b1;
        end
      end
    end

    // No request for mater m
    else if (i_wbm_cyc[m] == 'b0) begin
      for (c = 0; c < CHANNELS; c = c + 1) begin
        if (channel_in_use[c] == m) begin
          channel_in_use[c] = 0;
        end
      end
    end
  end

  // Loop over each channel
  for (c = 0; c < CHANNELS; c = c + 1) begin
    // Channel is addigned, connect the bus
    if (channel_in_use[c] != 0) begin
      o_wbc_we[c] <= i_wbm_we[channel_in_use[c]];
      o_wbc_cyc[c] <= i_wbm_cyc[channel_in_use[c]];
      o_wbc_stb[c] <= i_wbm_stb[channel_in_use[c]];
      o_wbc_addr[c * 32 + 31:0] <= i_wbm_addr[channel_in_use[c] * 32 + 31:0];
      o_wbc_data[c * 32 + 31:0] <= i_wbm_data[channel_in_use[c] * 32 + 31:0];
      o_wbm_err[channel_in_use[c]] <= i_wbc_err[c];
      o_wbm_ack[channel_in_use[c]] <= i_wbc_ack[c];
      o_wbm_stall[channel_in_use[c]] <= i_wbc_stall[c];
      o_wbm_data[channel_in_use[c] * 32 + 31:0] <= i_wbc_data[c * 32 + 31:0];
    end else begin
      o_wbc_we[c] <= 'b0;
      o_wbc_cyc[c] <= 'b0;
      o_wbc_stb[c] <= 'b0;
      o_wbc_addr[c * 32 + 31:0] <= 32'b0;
      o_wbc_data[c * 32 + 31:0] <= 32'b0;
      o_wbm_err[channel_in_use[c]] <= 'b0;
      o_wbm_ack[channel_in_use[c]] <= 'b0;
      o_wbm_stall[channel_in_use[c]] <='b0;
      o_wbm_data[channel_in_use[c] * 32 + 31:0] <= 32'b0;
    end
  end
end

endmodule


It would be nice if compilers would treat a for loop variable in a vector range as a constant, but all the other compilers I tried also generate errors (Cadence and Synopsys).  Here is a greatly simplified version of your code which still generates errors (due to i_wbc_mask[c : 0]):
module crossbar
  #(
    parameter MASTERS = 1,
    parameter CHANNELS = 1,
    parameter MASK_SIZE = 4
    )
   (
    input logic                              i_clock,
    input logic [$clog2(MASTERS):0]          i_wbm_cyc, // Cycle status
    input logic [MASTERS * 32 - 1:0]         i_wbm_addr, // Address read from master
    input logic [CHANNELS * MASK_SIZE - 1:0] i_wbc_mask    // Mask for address space
    );

   logic [$clog2(CHANNELS):0]                channel_in_use [$clog2(MASTERS):0];
   integer                                   m; // Master loop index
   integer                                   c; // Channel loop index

   always_ff @(posedge i_clock) begin
      for (m = 0; m < MASTERS; m = m + 1) begin
         if (i_wbm_cyc[m]) begin
            for (c = 0; c < CHANNELS; c = c + 1) begin
               if (i_wbc_mask[c : 0]) begin
                  channel_in_use[c] <= m;
               end
            end
         end
      end
   end
endmodule

This means you need to re-work your code to get it to compile.

The following is also a compile error because i_wbc_mask  is a variable, not a constant:
:i_wbc_mask * MASK_SIZE]


Your last for loop is outside the always_ff block making it think it is a generate-for loop. It would help if you labeled some of your blocks. Then you could keep better track of where
always_ff @(posedge i_clock) begin : main_ff
  for (int m = 0; m < MASTERS; m++) begin : master_loop
    ...
  end : master_loop
  for (int c = 0; c < MASTERS; c++) begin : channel_loop
    ...
  end : master_loop
end : main_ff

